# Converting comma separated list to unordered list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to convert a comma separated list to unordered list using jQuery.

This code seems to work:

```
var el = $('#list, #list1');
var values = el.html().split(',');
el.html('<ul>' + $.map(values, function(v) { 
  return '<li>' + v + '</li>';
}).join('') + '</ul>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v7rpL/11/

but it has an 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined ' issue in my end that causes my jQuery slider not to work.

Can someone help me derive this code to avoid the issue above? I believe the code is not clean enough.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't see any error on jsfiddle. Are you sure the problem is in that code snippet?

Comment: from my POV it's working

Comment: "Working" in heavy quotes. Try changing the list items in the second list and tell me it "works" ;)

Comment: There is no errors, this code seems quite operable

Comment: yeah, there's no error on fiddle but on the actual site it has one. but its okay now. thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of your code:

```
var el = $('#list, #list1');
```

does not return a single element but an array.

If you take a look at this [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/v7rpL/13/), I have changed one part of it.

```
var el = $('#list, #list1');

// run through each element of the returned list
$(el).each(function(key, val) {
    var values = $(val).html().split(',');
    $(val).html('<ul>' + $.map(values, function(v) { 
      return '<li>' + v + '</li>';
    }).join('') + '</ul>');
});
```

Also, if you change the html to:

```
<div id="list">list 1, list 2, list 3, list 4</div>
<div id="list1">list 5, list 6, list 7, list 8</div>
```

With your script, you will realise that it's gone pretty bad.

## Update

Another good solution keeping your script would be to generate a string out of the html of both the divs. Thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24159749/converting-comma-separated-list-to-unordered-list-in-jquery) by @Dominik.

Comment: or just do ```var theStuff = $('#list').html() + ',' + $('#list1').html();``` .... one less look ;)

Comment: @Aniket - Thanks a lot! Yeah, you've made a better version.

Comment: @Dominik - I don't really understand what you are trying to say but thanks for the help.

Comment: The method suggested by @Dominik is damn good. What he is basically doing is making a string from the html of both the divs. You do not need to do it for each of them individually using a loop, the way I have done. But that is only applicable when you manually want to write it down instead of using a common selector at the start.